# Dynamic URL in html+php string

Tags: php

i want to use variable+html in same code but it doesn't work for me..

```
<?php
$dBASEURL = "http://example.com/";



function stdhead(){ 
echo'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org   /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $dBASEURL . 'css/style.css"/>
...
```

Comment: and the question is... ?

Comment: What does doesn't work mean?

Comment: "' . $dBASEURL . 'css/style.css" this not work as "http://example.com/css/style.css"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you need to set the variable **$dBASEURL** as GLOBAL in your function so your code becomes

```
<?php
$dBASEURL = "http://example.com/";



function stdhead(){ 
GLOBAL $dBASEURL;
echo'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org              /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $dBASEURL . 'css/style.css"/>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with variable scope, your functions is not getting the variable, thus 
 You have to pass `$dBASEURL` to your function like:

```
<?php
$dBASEURL = "http://example.com/";

function stdhead($dBASEURL){ 

// echo anything + your variable
}
```